# revert to colourful panel icons in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, icons

I don't like the monochromatic panel icons and want to get back the colourful icons I had when using 11.10 (blue with green tick for dropbox, blue network manager, yellow sun in weather indicator, etc).  How can I do this? Is there a standard theme with colourful icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install  [myunity](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/myunity) [image: Install myunity].

You can change the icons and themes as below. Do go back to default theme and icon set. Click on `Default Settings`.

*Note: While changing icons,first choose `default settings`. Otherwise icons may not change correctly*

[image: change themes]

Comment: Perfect -- using this to select Radiance theme and default icons gave me what I was looking for -- thanks!