# Indicators showing the wrong color icons

Tags: indicator

I dont know whats wrong with My Ubuntu but my top panel was gone its proper look .Help me to restore it . i am giving you the sample image .[image]

Comment: have you been playing with themes? what happens if you change your theme in myunity/appearance screen?

Comment: @fossfreedom No changes are applying even i have changed my theme from appearance settings .I have Ubuntu tweek installed .

Comment: maybe the icon theme? I notice that the icons change with the thickness of the panel.

Comment: but how could i change it , i have tried with Ubuntu Tweek too by setting to default .

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129118/revert-to-colourful-panel-icons-in-12-04 , possibly

Comment: @mateo_salta i have installed it but its not opening .

Comment: somebody please help

Comment: the only other way I know is to manually change out the names of the icons on the theme, so we need to know the name of the theme you are using, to change out the icons, I had the same problem on my machine, it was showing a ugly gray wireless icon for the Internet instead of the normal colorful arrows, also what are the different indicators you are using, I can Identify the mail, network and sound, so if you say what the others are and the name of the theme you use, we can guide you through changing the icons out.

Comment: @mateo_salta could you please convert above comment of yours as your answer , i got solved with the issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the theme is using a smaller set of icons because of the thickness of the bar, or the icon theme got changed for the theme,if changing themes does not work try changing the icon theme for the theme or changing out individual icons in that theme. So here is an example using the default "Ambiance" theme.

So your icons look similar to this, worse in your case.

[image]

1. We need to locate where the icons and themes are located.

   `/usr/share/icons` is one place that icons are located.

   `/usr/share/themes` is where the themes are located, it will be `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance` for our example
2. In `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/index.theme` it will list what icon theme it is using. In this case it is using `ubuntu-mono-dark`

[image]

Next with that information navigate to `usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status`

This is where the status icons are, so then you need to select what pixel size your theme is using, from 16, 22, and 24. since your theme turned ugly it may be possible that it is using the 16 pixel icons.

But since you have a wired icon I don't think this is the case, For example the 16 folder does not contain `nm-device-wired.svg` an will use a different, most likely the wireless icon for the network.

You can then use `gksudo Nautilus` to be able to change the icons, in the folders.

---

Since it seems that all your icons are dark, I would suggest changing the icon theme from `usr/share/themes/Ambiance/index.theme` first. For example I changed `ubuntu-mono-dark` to `ubuntu-mono-light` to see what would happen, and it didn't take effect when just loging out then back in, so I had to change the theme to something else then back again for It to take effect, and It then looked like this- [image]
So you can then change that to any icon theme you have in `usr/share/icons`

Hopefully this will give you the basics so you can make your icons look however you want.